# How to change the numbering?

Tags: numbering, page-numbering

I would like to start numbering the document in the second page with the number 1. How can I do it?

Or, more generally put, how can I start with the number 1 in the page x?

Answer (score 1):

If it may be independent of a previous text and you can identify page x,

```
\setcounter{page}{1}
```

somewhere on the page x will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

[`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s `abspage` module uses [`atbegshi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi) to keep track of the *absolute* page number `\theabspage`, rather than the printer *logical* page number `\thepage`.

The example below conditions on the value of the `abspage` counter within the footer (at which time the page number is accurate). At the appropriate time (when the condition is met), `\startpagenumbering` is executed, which resets the value of the `page` counter and then self-destructs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{zref-abspage,lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\newcommand{\startpagenumbering}{%
  \setcounter{page}{1}%
  \gdef\startpagenumbering{}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Remove header/footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{%
  \ifnum\value{abspage}>48
    \startpagenumbering\thepage
  \fi
  /\theabspage}

\begin{document}

\sloppy% Just for this example
\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

Note that the absolute page numbering starts from 0.